# New FlowLayout after clicking on JButton

Tags: java, swing

I have some code:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
            JPanel windowPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
//          windowPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
            windowPanel.add(colorChooser);
            windowPanel.add(button);
            windowPanel.setVisible(true);
            mainFrame.add(windowPanel);
        }
    });
```

and the problem is how to display new `FlowLayout` (in a new window) after clicking a button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by swapping the `windowPanel.setVisible(true);` and `mainFrame.add(windowPanel);`

```
mainFrame.add(windowPanel);
windowPanel.setVisible(true);
```

Adding `mainFrame.pack()` before the `setVisible` call won't hurt either.

You may wish to take a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) before commiting yourself to a particulr design though.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame2 = new JFrame("Meine Frame");
            frame2.setSize(500,400);
            frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            JPanel windowPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            windowPanel.add(okButton);

            okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    color = colorChooser.getColor();
                    System.out.println("The selected color was:" + color);
                    panel.setBackground(color);
                    frame2.dispose();

                }
            });{

            };
            windowPanel.add(colorChooser);

            windowPanel.setVisible(true);
            frame2.add(windowPanel);
            frame2.setVisible(true);

        }
```

in this way I solved my problem.